# Angular 2 *ngFor does not print to table

Tags: html, angular2-template

I am new at using Angular and I was having problems displaying data retrieved from a database. Can someone help me understand why when I use *ngFor on this HTML code only the  gets displayed on my html but not the rest of the rows?

This is my HTML file

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contact contacts$">
            <td>{{ contact.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.phone_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.school }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my component.ts file

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from "./contacts.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Contact } from './contact'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
})

export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private router:Router, private contactService: ContactService )
  {}
    contacts$: Observable<Contact[]>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.contacts$ = this.contactService.getContacts();
    }
}
```

I am getting my information from a GET HTTP call and it works fine if I do the *ngFor on a  tag but it does not display when i use it on a  tag

Here is the code for when I do it on a

```html
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts$ | async" >
  {{contact.first_name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you are missing the `of` in your *ngFor tr tag. 
Your HTML code should be like below

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts$"> <!-- adding of to retrive data -->
            <td>{{ contact.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.phone_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.school }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing correct loop syntax like in this case you missing "of" and also cross check for correct Property Name.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <td>{{ contact.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.phone_number }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.school }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```